# Valid Formula in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am a little confused about the validity of `first order logic formulas`.

How we can using formal notation to prove the following is VALID?

> $ \exists x \exists y p(x,y) \to \neg \forall x \forall y \neg p(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to note that : $\lnot \forall$ is equivalent to $\exists \lnot$.

Thus the formula :

> $∃x∃yp(x,y) \to ¬∀x∀y¬p(x,y)$ is equivalent to :
>
> $∃x∃yp(x,y) → ∃x∃y¬¬p(x,y)$.

By *double negation*, this amounts to the *valid* formula :

> > $∃x∃yp(x,y) → ∃x∃yp(x,y)$.

---

For a "formal" proof we can use *Natural Deduction* to show that :

> $∃x∃yp(x,y) \vdash ¬∀x∀y¬p(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof: Just switch both quantifiers and remove the resulting double negation.

1. $\exists x: \exists y: P(x,y)$  (Premise)
2. $\neg \forall x: \neg \exists y: P(x,y)$  (Switch Quantifier)
3. $\neg \forall x: \neg \neg \forall y: \neg P(x,y)$  (Switch Quantifier)
4. $\neg \forall x:  \forall y: \neg P(x,y)$  (Remove $\neg\neg$)
5. $\exists x: \exists y: P(x,y)\implies \neg \forall x:  \forall y: \neg P(x,y)$  (Conclusion)